# Authenticate Vue 2 SPA via SAML 2.0 and ADFS

Tags: .net-core, vuejs2, saml-2.0, adfs

I have done quite a bit of research over the last few weeks and have not found a situation that quite fits my problem so I was hoping I could turn to the community. The high-level view of my scenario is this:

I have a Vue 2 SPA using a .NET Core Api with MS SQL Server on the back end. I have a requirement to add SAML SSO via ADFS 5.0 on Server 2019 (our ADFS is controlled by a separate team, I cannot access the ADFS servers at all).

I do have the xml metadata from the ADFS team so I know the IDP entity ID, signing cert, etc. I would prefer to handle the authentication on the JS side if possible, the idea being that my SPA would route them to the SSO login so we can utilize Username/Password OR PIV token, then route my user back to my application.

I am honestly not sure where to even start. The similar issues I have found don't line up with what we need to do. I am happy to provide as many details as I can wherever possible. What I am hoping to learn is, effectively, the following:

1. Start here, create this config in this location
2. Set up the reroute
3. Set this up in adfs
4. Read the response from adfs and establish user access level
5. User can access my application according to their permissions.

Thank you in advance,

Drew

**Edit**

A little more info I forgot to mention. My Vue SPA is hosted on a remote web server on a separate domain than our ADFS server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone who stumbles across this post in a similar situation, the answer turned out to be that we needed to create a .NET web app to leverage WS Federation which met our authentication needs. This arlicle proved very helpful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

SAML is not suitable to with a SPA. One reason is that the resulting SAML assertion comming from ADFS is send using POST which client side code can not read. Another is that SAML is based on secrets that need to be stored on the application side. This can not be done securely in client side code.

There are different was to approach this. Many suggest to just use OpenID Connect and Oauth instead. But as you say you do can not need to use SAML.

One solution to this that I like is to use a ID broker to translate between OpenID connect, used by the SPA and SAML used by the ADFS IdP. This way you also get a SPA that uses a standard protocol for authentication.

Keycloak is a good free alternative to use as an identity broker.

A little while back I wrote [a blog post on how to set up just this](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/post/saml-for-react-spa/), using ADFS, Keycloak and a React SPA. There is a also a automated demo environment in Vagrant and virtual box you can use to test this solution for Vue.

While this is not directly based on Vue I think it is a small thing to get this working, as it is based on a standard. For example using [this post](https://damienbod.com/2019/01/29/securing-a-vue-js-app-using-openid-connect-code-flow-with-pkce-and-identityserver4/)

Comment: Would SAML be any more suitable if I focused my authentication efforts on the .NET Core side instead of Vue JS? I know our ADFS 'supports' OpenID Connect, but I was led to believe that my app would need to be in Azure for that.

Comment: Seems there might be a few options then. I cant see that you would need to be in azure to authenticate using OpenID connect towards ADFS. That would be my first choise. Next there are libraries to .net Core see. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp
If that doesnt work go for the brokering method.